# C++ access class struct member using an array pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Sorry if the title doesn't make sense. I don't know how to word it as I'm fairly new to C++. Basically I have this:

```
sf::VertexArray *vArray;
```

If I want to access the `position` inside, I would have to do this:

```
(*vArray)[0].position = ...;
```

Is there a way to use the arrow notation instead? Why can't I do this: `vArray[0]->position = ...;`?

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**: `sf::VertexArray` is part of the SFML library: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/VertexArray.cpp

Comment: Since `vArray` has type `sf::VertexArray *`, `vArray[0]` is just built-in pointer arithmetic, and has type `sf::VertexArray`. That type has no `operator->`, and so you cannot do `->position` on it. Even if it did have `sf::Vertex *operator->()`, presumably it would be implemented to return a pointer to the first vertex in the VertexArray, so would only have quite limited use. I expect that's why it's not provided.

Comment: Thank you, it makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: If you have dozens of lines that use **(*vArray)** inside a block, you could reseat it as reference and use that reference (be careful not to **delete** the vArray pointer before the end of the block)

    vector<int> *pvi=new vector<int>(2,100);
    vector<int> &vref=(*pvi);
    cout << vref[0] << endl;
    cout << vref[1] << endl;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your original line

```
(*vArray)[0].position = ...;
```

properly illustrates the semantics of your data structure, then the `->`-based analogue would be

```
vArray->operator [](0).position = ...;
```

assuming `sf::VertexArray` is a class type with overloaded operator `[]`. Obviously this second form is much more convoluted and requires an explicit reference to the operator member function, which is why it is a better idea to use a much more elegant first form.

Alternatively, you can force a `->` into this expression as

```
(&(*vArray)[0])->position = ...;
```

but that does not make much practical sense.

You can even combine the two

```
(&vArray->operator [](0))->position = ...;
```

to arrive at something even more obfuscated and pointless.

Anyway, why do you want to have a `->` in this expression? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was just trying to set the `position`. I'm fairly new to C++ so I don't know how most of the syntax works; especially for pointers.